# Google Calendar API v3: Access Not Configured. The API (Calendar API) is not enabled for your project

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I download the calendar-android-sample under https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples, and make no change of the source code,and follow the develop console help to create the client ID for android,But when i run the calendar-android-sample application, i got error:

> W/System.err(32741):
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403
>   Forbidden
>
> W/System.err(32741):   "code": 403,
>
> W/System.err(32741):   "errors": [
>
> W/System.err(32741):     {
>
> W/System.err(32741):       "domain": "usageLimits",
>
> W/System.err(32741):       "message": "Access Not Configured. The API
>   (Calendar API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google
>   Developers Console to update your configuration.",
>
> W/System.err(32741):       "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
>
> W/System.err(32741):       "extendedHelp":
>   "https://console.developers.google.com"
>
> W/System.err(32741):     }
>
> W/System.err(32741):   ],
>
> W/System.err(32741):   "message": "Access Not Configured. The API
>   (Calendar API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google
>   Developers Console to update your configuration."
>
> W/System.err(32741): }

I already enabled the Calendar API but still get this error,anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: This error occurs when the API's your project are using are not enabled on the developers console. Did you enable Calendar API(and all the API's your application is trying to access) on developers console?

Comment: Yes i enabled the Calendar API of course. When using OAuth2, where the api key should i put, or it will connect the API itself when using OAuth2?  If it will connect the API itself, how this happens? Is it depend on the application name when setApplicationName("xxx") ?

Comment: @Mercedes You need to put your API key and associated credentials in order to make OAuth2 work.

Comment: @FurhanShabir  Could you make it more specific? Where should i put the API key,any API function? Thanks a lot !

Comment: @FurhanShabir   In this page, https://developers.google.com/console/help/#generatingdevkeys  it said **For Android and iOS keys, add the value shown in the "API key" section of the Console to your application (for example, as an attribute in your AndroidManifest.xml)** , but i don't know what the attribute is, i tried <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.calendar.v3.API_KEY" android:value="mykey", but useless. Someone tole me we don't need the api key, so i'm confused now.

Comment: @FurhanShabir  Here is my code:`credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR));
    SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    credential.setSelectedAccountName(settings.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null));
    // Calendar client
    client = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
        transport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName("applicationname")
        .build();
        CalendarList feed = client.calendarList().list().setFields(CalendarInfo.FEED_FIELDS).execute();`

Answer (score 0):

As I read the documentation for google calender api through the below url.
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android

But as I find the problem with the documentation that they have not added two user permission to fetch data from the calender api.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```

I have add these above permission in my case then its work fine. Hopefully its work for you as well.

Answer (score -1):

Check the following link for step-by-step instructions for using Google Calendar API for Android:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android